# Component is not showing in Sitecore EXM editor unless it is saved

Tags: exm

When editing the email in the `Email Experience Manager`, click the `Add a new component` button. 
Added Image component by clicking on `+ Add here` buttons.

After adding nothing was shown but after saving, page got reloaded and component can be seen.

Comment: What Sitecore version you are using?

Comment: Sitecore 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)

Comment: Can you see any error in console?

Comment: No. There are no errors in console.